# Putting spaces between two divs in the same line

Tags: html, css

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="boxed" style="background-image: url(http://images.glaciermedia.ca/polopoly_fs/1.1195672.1404743845!/fileImage/httpImage/image.jpg_gen/derivatives/box_100/wanted-man-07-jpg.jpg);">
</div>
<div class="boxed" style="background-image: url(http://images.glaciermedia.ca/polopoly_fs/1.1195672.1404743845!/fileImage/httpImage/image.jpg_gen/derivatives/box_100/wanted-man-07-jpg.jpg);">
</div>
```

And this is my CSS code:

```
.boxed {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border: 2px solid #3eade1;
border-radius: %50;
-webkit-border-radius: 75px;
    -moz-border-radius: 75px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
display: table-cell;
border-spacing: 10px;
}


.boxed img {

    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

And this is the output:

[image]

I'm trying to add some spaces between two divs, but I couldn't manage to do it by looking at the answers for older questions in here. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: And/or [`padding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding) (given that these are `display: table-cell` for some reason).

Comment: @DavidThomas padding is inside the element, margin is outside, would work better for this case

Comment: `border-radius: %50;`??

Comment: @mmeasor: yes, I know where it goes. The reason I suggest `padding` is because I can't remember if `margin` is applied to `display: table-cell` elements (I don't recall it being applied to `<td>` elements, for example, where `padding` was used to space the contents (and/or `cell-spacing` which couldn't be fine-tuned).

Comment: I don't think margin or padding will work here. The cells are empty anyway. I'd change the table cell display to floats instead, then apply margins.

Comment: Oh table-cells, use border-spacing on the table-cell parent element assuming it is display table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you must keep the `display: table-cell` then you can use the `border` to separate the `<div>` elements. This means to keep, or to *emulate*, the original border we need to use an inset `box-shadow` and then also clip the background so that it doesn't extend under the transparent borders (that we're using as spacers). Your original CSS is therefore amended to the following:

```
.boxed {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 75px;
    -moz-border-radius: 75px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: table-cell;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #3eade1;
    border: 5px solid transparent;
    -moz-background-clip: padding;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding;
    background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/m2nmJ/).

References:

- [`background-clip`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip).
- [`box-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow).

Comment: That's already in his question though, I assumed it hadn't worked (and it had no effect for me in JS Fiddle when I pasted his HTML and CSS into it).

Comment: OP put it on the wrong place, http://jsfiddle.net/Ebf6D/ it need to apply to the table-cell element's parent (display table element)

Answer (score 1):

I have a different approach, normally `display: table-cell` value doesn't work with margins. Instead you can use `display: inline-block;` if you are OK with that then you can apply margin.

```
.boxed {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        border: 2px solid #3eade1;
        border-radius: %50;
        -webkit-border-radius: 75px;
        -moz-border-radius: 75px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left:5px;
        margin-right:5px;
}
```

[JS Fiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eEu2p/)

You can also check margin is compliant with which display values [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin).

If you want to put names underneath your pictures you can also check my second option. You can put spans and change their position as absolute and put some margins on it.

```
<div class="boxed" style="background-image: url(http://images.glaciermedia.ca/polopoly_fs/1.1195672.1404743845!/fileImage/httpImage/image.jpg_gen/derivatives/box_100/wanted-man-07-jpg.jpg);">
    <span>Prince Charles</span>
</div>

span
{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 110px;
}
```

The result will be like this.

[JS Fiddle for second option.](http://jsfiddle.net/eEu2p/1/)

[image]

Comment: This approach works as well for adding space between two divs. However, when I apply this and write some texts after div's, they are placed to the same line as div's but I want them to be in the next line. Thanks.

Comment: @BurakKarakuş, I updated my answer. I hope it can answer your question.